# dataweave mapping from an array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a basic dataweave mapping function. I want to have a number of objects with a simple array as input:
I have created the function generatePoints to achive this

```
fun generatePoints() = [1 to 24] map {
        currentyear: 2023,
        points: $[$$],
}
```

It returns a single array:

```
[
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 1
  }
]
```

But it should return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 1
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 2
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 3
  }
.....
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": n
  }
]
```

Does anybody know how to update the generatePoints function to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 to 24` is already a range with type array. Therefore you have to remove the `[]` around it. As it is creating an Array with a single "array" element.

Comment: Thx Harsbank, yes of course, silly that I didn't see that myself

Answer (score 0):

A little change of your solution:

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
[1 to 24][0] map {
        currentyear: 2023,
        points: $,
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 1
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 2
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 3
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 4
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 5
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 6
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 7
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 8
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "currentyear": 2023,
    "points": 10
  } ...
```

Comment: Using the selector to get the first element (`[0]`) is unnecessary and adds extra operations if you avoid creating and extra array around the range. See @Harshank answer instead.